# Asymptotic growth rate of a double while loop algorithm with an outer loop executed log(n) times

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

What is the asymptotic growth rate (depending on `n`) of this algorithm ?

```
i = 1; // executed 1 time
while( i ≤ n) {
    j = 1; // executed log(n) times

    while( j ≤ i) {
       j = j + 1; // ?
    }

    i = 2*i; // executed log(n) times
}
```

When n equals 10 :

```
| i iterations | j itérations
| i=1          | j=1
| i=2          | j=1 j=2 
| i=4          | j=1 j=2 j=3 j=4
| i=8          | j=1 j=2 j=3 j=4 j=5 j=6 j=7 j=8
```

The outer loop(i) affectations are executed `log(n)` times

How many times is the inner loop(j) affectation executed ?

Comment: any attempts from your side? If you have no idea, you could simply measure it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be `O(n)`.

The last iteration of the outer loop has `n` iterations of the inner loop.  The second-to-last iteration of the outer loop has `n/2` iterations of the inner loop.  The third-to-last iteration has `n/4`:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 2*n
```

See [geometric progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) for the formula that allows you to compute the sum.

Answer (score 0):

When n is four, the last execution of the outer loop causes the inner loop to execute 4 times.  When you double n from 4 to 8, the outer loop is executed one more time, and on that last execution of the outer loop the inner loop is executed 8 times.  Double it again to 16, and the outer loop will execute once more, with the inner loop going 16 times.  So doubling the input causes a doubling in the execution time (plus the time for that one more outer loop, which become insignificant as n gets large).

So O(n).